# error:no resource identifier found for attribute"showAsAction" in package android

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-menu

I've been working on an Android project and encountered an error which I'm unable to solve for quite a while. Here is the error which says

```
error:no resource identifier found for attribute"showAsAction"
```

in package `android`

and the error is in following file `login_.xml`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

Comment: because `android:showAsAction` does not exist. Where have you seen that referenced before, just out of curiosity?

Comment: @TronicZomB [`android:showAsAction`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) is used when creating action bar items to hint to the system whether or not an item should be shown on the bar, shown with text, shown only if room is available, or shown in the overflow drop down.

Comment: @user2146931 What is your build target?

Comment: OHHH! Ok, that would make sense why I am not familiar with it then since I have not worked with the action bar yet. Thank you for the clarification @MCeley!

Answer (score 5):

This attribute is introduced in API level 11. Check the min and target version of your app in Manifest file.

Answer (score 5):

"ShowAsAction" attribute is introduced in api 11. Change the minSdkVersion of your app in Manifest file.

If you want to use it for api lower than 11, then you have to use android support library "android.support.v4.app".

After importing support library, you have to make some changes in your login.xml file. for e.g replace "**android:showAsAtion attribute**" by "**yourapp:showAsAction**" and define "yourapp" in header in this way.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    yourapp:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: My minimum sdk version is 14, but still facing this same problem

Answer (score -2):

Just remove android:showAsAction from xml file