# "No resource identifier found" In menu resource files after refactoring android studio project

Tags: java, android, xml

I have recently done some major refactoring to my android studio project as it gets closer and closer to an actual release. Anyways, I have about 6 menu resource files that all have the header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

that build with my project fine. After coming back and adding 3 new menu resource files (it's a large project) I am getting this error:

```
Error:(10) No resource identifier found for attribute 'shows action' in package 'com.codemine.pcpartpicker
```

This only happens with the newly added menu resource files, Gradle still builds if I remove this and only have the old ones, what makes this even stranger is that the error reports there is no package in

`com.codemine.pcpartpicker`

when my projects package is

`com.codemine.unofficial.pcpartpicker`

Here is my manifest as I have some suspicion that the problem lies there...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.codemine.unofficial.pcpartpicker">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".CPUActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CPUCoolerActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MotherboardActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MemoryActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".GpuActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".StorageActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CaseActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PowerActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MonitorActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Edit: Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.codemine.unofficial.pcpartpicker'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //for cardView
    //for jsoup, grabs dependency from maven central
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been an extremely frustrating error to fix, mostly because I was looking in the wrong place to fix it. It seems this happens after changing the project *and* adding new resource files (I only ran into trouble with menus, but im speculating it could happen with any resource files). It seems there is some error with the IDE/Gradle, where it seems to want to reference a version of the file in the *previous package* even though this package no longer exists. As you can see my java, manifest, menu etc is correct, the problem lies elsewhere.

**The solution**

I copied my resource files into n++ and deleted them from the project then performed a build>clean Project which should complete successfully after commenting out some lines. Then I deleted the menu resource files and added them back **with different names, this is important**. At this point **do not paste your old code back into them**. Add an Item without any attributes from `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`, make sure the project builds succesfully  and then add something from there and have **android studio edit the namespace for you**. Updating the namespace yourself will not do the trick, trust me I know.

This was a very niche but frusterating problem, hopefully no one else runs into it.

Answer (score 0):

Previous similar questions have been answered on Stack Exchange by suggesting the minSDKVersion must be over 11 for showsaction, but I see yours is set to 15. See:

[error:no resource identifier found for attribute"showAsAction" in package android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703570/errorno-resource-identifier-found-for-attributeshowasaction-in-package-androi)

Having said that, given you have done a major refactor, perhaps it is pointing to an old build.gradle with lower minSDKVersion in someway. In similar situations with an IDE I have found a rebuild can help. Perhaps worth a try. Good luck.

Comment: Hmm, I havent committed the changes yet because they are broken, but do you think if I tried pulling the project up on another computer that may be a good indicator of what the problem is?

Comment: Might indicate. I am not certain of the lifecycle of the project or your recent refactoring, but I wondered if for some reason package names of com.codemine.pcpartpicker and com.codemine.unofficial.pcpartpicker had both been used and this had confused the ide. I wondered if the 'unofficial' was the redevelopment version and the other was the production version or something similar. Apologies if this isn't helping as I am not sure of the project background.

Comment: I assumed you only pasted part of your manifest file, I assume you must have the manifest XML Elements with the correct  package string etc. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html